# Laravel : Migration table created successfully, but the tables don't getting created at all

Tags: laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I run my migrations but in the migrate mysql table don't appear all the migrations classes.

These are my migrations

[image]

And this is the migration table:

[image]

As you can see, the last migration registered in the table is from 2014-09-25, but I have till 2014-12-03 migration class.

It looks weird, doesn't it?

Comment: Please show the snippet for creating table, or paste one sample file here

Comment: How is your config/app.php file?

Comment: There might be an error in compromiso migration that's breaking it. Are there error messages when running migrate?

Comment: Is there an actual answer here?

Comment: ah, if you run `artisan migrate` (or, `php artisan migrate`), then you might get some errors -- whereas 'creating the migration' is just creating the '....migration...' file itself.

to actually affect your db schema, you need to actually run one of the migration commands.

i had a further issue -- i had aliased in my .bashrc an 'artisan' command in another directory. that created some fun/weird errors. (e.g. `alias artisan=/path/to/specific/project/foo/artisan`)